# Extract phone numbers and exclude extraneous characters

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a regex which will extract a complete phone number from a string (which is the only thing in the string) but leaving out any cruft like decorative brackets, etc.

The pattern I have mostly appears to work, but returns a list of matches - whereas I want it to return the phone number with the characters removed. Unfortunately, it completely fails if I add the start and end of line matchers...

```
^(?!\(\d+\)\s*){1}(?:[\+\d\s]*)$
```

Without the `^` and `$` this matches the following numbers:

`12345-678-901` returns three groups: `12345` `678` `901`

`+44-123-4567-8901` returns four groups: `+44` `123` `4567` `8901`

`(+48) 123 456 7890` returns four groups: `+48` `123` `456` `7890`

How can I get the groups to be returned as a single, joined up whole?

Other than that, the only change I would like to include is to return nothing if there are any non-numeric, non-bracket, non-`+` characters anywhere. So, this should fail:

```
(+48) 123 burger 7890
```

Comment: Such a simple task if you regex is not requirement (which I think makes it impossible as I don't believe regex can represent dis-joined ranges as single result)

Comment: I'm happy to accept a C# answer which does not use regex (hence the lack of `regex` in the post title)

Comment: Something like `((Func<string,string>)(s=>!s.All(c=> "+-()0123456789 ".Contains(c))?"FAIL" :string.Join("", s.Where(c=>"0123456789".Contains(c))))) ("+12 22")` (also couple separate regex one for math you have and another for replace as Caius suggested would be simpler)

Comment: Note: I also struggle with the statement: *I'm trying to create a regex which will extract a complete phone number from a string (which is the only thing in the string)*, - to me this means `(+48) 123 burger 7890` is a phone number and just needs the burger stripping out which `Regex.Replace(..., "[^0-9+]","")` will do. Alternatively if it's like and American style 1800-DISNEY why not translate the burger back to numbers so you can keep the data?

Comment: @caius-jard The `burger` does not need translating, it simply needs removing. I see the point to your question. Would your regex also extract the parenthesised country code, etc?

Comment: Extract isn't the word I would use because that sounds like your aim is to keep the number as separate groups (a parsing into country/area/local operation). My Regex simply replaces all non phone number chars with nothing, leaving you with a string that is a cleaned phone number. Applying a replace of `"[^0-9+]"` with `""` would convert `(+48) 123 burger 7890 --> +481237890` and `(+48) 123 456 7890 --> +481234567890`; there isn't any extracting into N groups going on here - it's just dirty string in, clean string out

Answer (score 1):

I'd keep it simple, makes it more readable and maintainable:

```
public string CleanPhoneNumber(string messynumber){

    if(Regex.IsMatch(messynumber, "[a-z]"))
      return "";
    else
      return Regex.Replace(messynumber, "[^0-9+]", "");

}
```

If any alphameric characters are present (extend this range if you wish) return blank else replace every char that is not 0-9 or +, with nothing. This produces output like `0123456789` and `+481234567` with all the brackets, spaces and hyphens etc removed too. If you want to keep those in the output, add them to the Regex

Side note: It's not immediately clear or me what you think is *"cruft" that should be stripped* (non a-z?) and what you think is *"cruft" that should cause blank* (a-z?). I struggled with this because you said (paraphrase) "non digit, non bracket, non plus should cause blank" but earlier in your examples your processing permitted numbers that had *hyphens and also spaces* - being strictly demanding of spec hyphens/spaces would be "cruft that causes the whole thing to return blank" too

I've assumed that it's lowercase chars from the "burger" example but as noted you can extend the range in the IF part should you need to include other chars that return blank

If you have a lot of them to do maybe pre compile a regex as a class level variable and use it in the method:

```
private Regex _strip = new Regex( "[^0-9+]", RegexOptions.Compiled);

public string CleanPhoneNumber(string messynumber){

    if(Regex.IsMatch(messynumber, "[a-z]"))
      return "";
    else
      return _strip.Replace(messynumber, "");
}
...

for(int x = 0; x < millionStrArray.Length; x++)
  millionStrArray[x] = CleanPhoneNumber(millionStrArray[x], "");
```

I don't think you'll gain much from compiling the IsMatch one but you could try it in a similar pattern

Other options exist if you're avoiding regex, you cold even do it using LINQ, or looping on char arrays, stringbuilders etc. Regex is probably the easiest in terms of short maintainable code

Answer (score 0):

The strategy here is to use a look ahead and kick out (fail) a match if word characters are found.

Then when there are no characters, it then *captures* the `+` and all numbers into a match group named "Phone". We then extract that from the match's "Phone" capture group and combine as such:

```
string pattern = @"
^
(?=[\W\d+\s]+\Z) # Only allows Non Words, decimals and spaces; stop match if letters found
(?<Phone>\+?)    # If a plus found at the beginning; allow it
(                   # Group begin
   (?:\W*)            # Match but don't *capture* any non numbers
   (?<Phone>[\d]+)    # Put the numbers in.
)+                  # 1 to many numbers.

";

var number = "+44-123-33-8901";
var phoneNumber =
    string.Join(string.Empty,
        Regex.Match(number, 
                    pattern,
                    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace  // Allows us to comment the pattern
                  ).Groups["Phone"]
                    .Captures
                    .OfType<Capture>()
                    .Select(cp => cp.Value));

// phoneNumber is `+44123338901`
```

---

If one looks a the match structure, the data it houses is this:

```
Match #0
              [0]:  +44-123-33-8901
      ["1"] → [1]:  -8901
      →1 Captures:  44, -123, -33, -8901
  ["Phone"] → [2]:  8901
      →2 Captures:  +, 44, 123, 33, 8901
```

As you can see match[0] contains the whole match, but we only need the captures under the "Phone" group. With those captures { +, 44, 123, 33, 8901 } we now can bring them all back together by the `string.Join`.